# Entity Framework - LINQ - Dynamic Column Names

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, entity-framework-6

I know that this question was asked several times but the more answers I came accross the more I got confused.

Given I have a table `Categories` and within this table columns: `Category1`, `Category2`, `Category3` and so on.. How can I write a method like below and use a parameter (in this case `catno`)

As simplified as I could get;

```
public List<string> GetProductCategories(int catno)
{
    using (var ctx = new myEntities())
    {
        return (from c in ctx.Categories
                select c.Category1).ToList();
               //1 being the catno parameter obviously
    }
}
```

I definitely **DO NOT** want to use the Dynamic Linq library as it is not type safe. And although (and obviously) a working answer would do fine, a detailed explanation to the problem and the solution is provided.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you want complete typesafety, I don't see any other way than to use a switch case to map the integer to its corresponding category:

```
public List<string> GetProductCategories(int catno)
{
    using (var ctx = new myEntities())
    {
        switch (catno)
        {
            case 1:
                return ctx.Categories.Select(c => c.Category1).ToList();
            case 2:
                return ctx.Categories.Select(c => c.Category2).ToList();
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Category number not supported!");
        }
    }
}
```

Another thing you can obviously do is to refactor your code so that you have a list of Category classes that contain your string property as well as the number, then you can write something like this:

```
return ctx.Categories.Where(c => c.CategoryNumber == catno)
    .Select(c => c.CategoryDescription)
    .ToList();
```

I think you should probably refactor your code. I smell bad design when I see "Category1" and "Category2", it sounds like these should be items in a list of Categories.

Also a comment about Dynamic Linq, there's nothing wrong with using dynamic linq if for example you get a request from a client that is out of your control. You can simply return an error if the property is not found.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Agree with the bad design though it does not belong to me however this situation might arise at a different circumstances so its good to know the possible approaches to the matter. Also, although mapping sounds a good idea there are certain situations (e.g. db views) where columns might also be generated automatically. Your second suggestion on refactoring, I will try. This approach is quite new to me. As for Dynamic LINQ I agree with you up to a certain extend. But then again, If I feel myself at that point, I'd probably go for plain SQL instead!

Answer (score 1):

You can define expression that selects the property based on string name. Then in `IQueryable` interface you can use it in `Select` argument. You would need to use method syntax for it though:

```
public List<string> GetProductCategories(int catno)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Category));
    var property = Expression.Property(parameter, $"Category{catno}");
    var selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<Category, string>>(property, parameter);

    using (var ctx = new myEntities())
    {
        return ctx.Categories
            .Select(selector)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

`Expression.Property` method is performing some type checks so if on type `Category` there is no given property defined it will thrown an excpetion. For example this will fail if there is no `Category0` property:

```
var property = Expression.Property(parameter, "Category0");
```

Comment: I would advise against manually writing Expressions, they might not behave in a way you'd expect and can lead to some problems. Instead just use the [Dynamic LINQ Library](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) which allows you to write queries like this: `list.OrderBy("Category ASC")` to sort in ascending order.

Comment: Thanks Shahin, I explicitly mentioned that I do not want to use Dynamic LINQ for various reasons. Well that aside, what possible problems might arise with the expressions? It would really be good to note down since I have no idea. Thanks..

Comment: @KemalEmin @ ShahinDohan Expression API is safe (it checks types etc) and it's built-in library not third party like Dynamic LINQ (and such libraries can be unstable). It was created to simplify generating IL code so no IL knowledge is needed and also to represent code as data type so you can easily change it to another form e.g. SQL. All the IQueryable LINQ and EF is based on it. I've never encountered any problems with it.

Comment: Writing expressions is just as dynamic as using the library, except those who wrote that library probably know what they're doing. What you choose is up to you, but from my experience writing expressions, especially useful and reusable ones, is hard and easily breakable and hard to maintain. We even had some memory leaking issues related to them, so we ended up just ditching the whole thing.

Comment: @ShahinDohan That's more advanced concept in programming and when someone is on enough level of proficiency it's no any problem for them to write such expressions correctly without issues. The above one is extremely simple and it's the same as `Expression<Func<Category, string>> selector = c => c.Category1` for `catno = 1` meaning it will be lowered to the same code using Expression API. I don't believe anyone can have any issue with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<string> GetProductCategories(int catno)
{
    string catName = string.Format("Category{0}", catno);
    using (var ctx = new myEntities())
    {
        var result = ctx.Categories.Select(x => {
                var prop = x.GetType().GetProperty(catName);
                if (prop == null)
                {
                    return double.NaN;
                }
                return double.Parse(prop.GetValue(x).ToString());
            }).ToList();
        return result.Where(x => !double.IsNaN(x)).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: well done! Congratulations on adding your first answer on StackOverflow network. I would recommend editing your answer to explain your approach and what your code is doing.